# Check if a number exists in an entire JSON file using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I imported a CSV file as a JSON file to my firebase database, the database contains a list of vehicle plate numbers and some other irrelevant information, what I want to do is to check if a car number exists, and if it is, set a flag to true.

The database looks something like this, the number I want to check is the first value of them: [image: JSON]

In my code, I pretty much got stuck at this stage of the function:

```
    number = 4932564 //example number
    Boolean carExists = false;
    dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("rechev-6c");

    //here I want to scroll through all the childs and check of a the number exists

    }
```

That's because I don't know what child to pick, I need somehow to loop through every child there is to "rechev-6c" databse and then check if any of its keys contains the vehicle number I want, and if it is, set the flag to true.

Thanks for any sort of help.

Comment: If you are just looking for one child, why don't you build a reference to just that one, query it, and see if it contains any data instead of pulling down the entire thing?

Comment: `4932564` would be a key in the database? As `99099` is in your screenshot?  Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @DougStevenson I am looking for just child, but I do not know what child it is, because I need to iterate through them until the key is found.

Comment: @AlexMamo No, ```4932564``` would be a value in the first row under ``MISPAR RECHEV```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with a query:

```
dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("rechev-6c");
String property = "MISPAR RECHEV|TAARICH||HAFAKAT TAG|SUG TAG"
Query query = dbref.orderByChild(property).equalTo("04932564")

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      System.out.println(snapshot.getKey()); // 99099, or similar
      System.out.println(snapshot.child(property).getValue(String.class)); 
    }
 }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
}
```

A few things to note:

- Firebase can only query values at a fixed/known path, so this only works if the property name ("MISPAR...") can be hard-coded, which it seems to be in your case.
- Firebase can only match strings that **start with** a certain value, which is why I added a leading `0` to the value in `equalTo`. There is no option to filter strings that **contain** a certain value.